# Scala Slick: groupBy with nullable column

Tags: scala, slick

I am trying to get all results from a nullable column using Scala 2.11 + Slick 3.1.0 + Evolutions + H2 database. When executing groupBy operations over NOT NULL columns everything works as expected. However, if the column is nullable, when we run this this:

```
def listAllTenants(): Future[Seq[String]] = {
    dbConfig.db.run(metrics.groupBy(metric => metric.tenant)
    .map {
        case (tenant, group) => tenant
    }.result)
 }
```

Where:

```
create table `METRIC` (

    (...)

    `tenant` VARCHAR(255),
);
```

A exception is thrown:

```
[error] c.w.g.c.ErrorHandler - Error while processing request. Exception> slick.SlickException: Read NULL value (null) for ResultSet column <computed>
```

I have searched and tried adding an extra case trying to cover empty or null values, but it didn't work, or perhaps my case was incorrect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you defined the column as optional in your table representation?

Comment: Yes, I already did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the column should be nullable, ie: `def tenant = column[Option[String]]def tenant = column[Option[String]]`.

Indeed, when doing `metrics.groupBy(_.tenant).map { case (tenant, group) => tenant }` the result `Seq` may contain a null value which cause the NPE you mention.

Comment: This works! I thought I just need to specify if a field was optional or not in the mapping part and of course in the SQL table definition. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have a nullable column, Slick should instead return an `Option[T]` based on your query, but from what I read, group by is kind of buggy for a lot of instances, so I might be wrong in assuming it should return option.

There is some more information in the documentation that might help you.
http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.0/sql-to-slick.html#id19

but it also feels like you might running into something that isn't supported like here:
https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1285

Comment: The return type is an Option[String]. It is properly added in my table definition.

Comment: It sounds like what you are running into then might not be intended, maybe ping the people in the slick gitter, they might be able to help more with it.